# How do I add an alias to the table

Tags: mysql, subquery, group-by, alias

```
SELECT MAX(COUNT), A.id FROM
(
    SELECT supplier_id as id, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM `library`.`lms_book_details`
    GROUP BY supplier_id
) GROUP BY A.id;
```

While executing the query, MySQL gives an error:

> Every Derived table must have its own alias.

How do I add an alias to this?

Comment: Add A after the closing parenthesis.It looks like a messed up query for a test.

Comment: I guess your actual query is different because you don't need a derived table for the above. You are grouping by `supplier_id` in both the derived table and the external query.

Comment: @ypercube Why do you think it doesn`t need an alias?

Comment: @Mihai where did I say that?

Comment: @ypercube Apparently my parsing has bugs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like

```
SELECT MAX(A.count_supplier), A.id FROM
(
    SELECT supplier_id as id, COUNT(*) AS count_supplier
    FROM library.lms_book_details
    GROUP BY supplier_id
) A GROUP BY A.id;
```

Alias inner `COUNT(*)` as something different than `COUNT` as it is good practice to not use it as alias , As i have used `count_supplier`.

Comment: `COUNT` is not reserved but it's good practice to not use it as alias.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(COUNT), A.id FROM
(
                        SELECT supplier_id as id, COUNT(*) AS count
                        FROM library.lms_book_details
                        GROUP BY supplier_id
) as A GROUP BY A.id;
```

Comment: Why `as alias` Where is table A. This query will throw syntax error

Comment: @AbdulManaf, yes sir i have give just example name :)

Comment: There should also be space between `FROM` and `library.lms_book_details`, Please check the query syntax before posting answer

Comment: Please don't use `as <tablealias>` but just `<whitespace><tablealias>` when defining table aliases, and only use `as` when defining column aliases.

Comment: @Colin'tHart Any reason for this?

Comment: It's confusing and unnecessary.

Comment: @Colin'tHart It's unnecessary for columns as well. Whether it is confusing or not, depends on the reader, right?

Comment: @ypercube Hmm, there goes my argument. I was under the impression that `as` was required for columns...